# Time of day service for raspberry pi (port 37)

Tags: raspbian

I need to host a 'time of day' service on my Raspberry Pi. This is not `ntp` and it runs on port 37.

I'm unable to find anything online.  Everything is targeting NTP.  How do I install and enable `TOD` server for Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to install xinetd and configure time (port 37) on that.

Make sure you remove everything from /etc/xinetd.d that you don't want to use. Some of those services have a security profile that is unacceptable in the 21st century.

Comment: Any guidance on how to install it. Looks like its been replaced for the most part.

Comment: `sudo apt install xinetd`